# Wait Till All Thread Finish Processing Each WebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, httpwebrequest, threadpool

I am building a threading program in C# .Net4.0 and I ran into some issue.

I am using threadpool and callback. Below is my code in Main().

```
string[] urls = { url1, url2, url3, url4 };
callBack = new WaitCallback(PooledFunc);
for (int i = 0; i < urls.Length; i++)
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callBack, urls[i]);
```

I also have a function that will get response from the urls

```
static void PooledFunc(object url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

    // Get the response.
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream Answer = response.GetResponseStream();

    // Display the status.
    Console.WriteLine(response.Headers);
    StreamReader _Answer = new StreamReader(Answer);

    string content = _Answer.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(content);
}
```

I put some test prints in there, and with the above code, the program looks like it started all threads but terminate before all of them went through, and everytime is different.

When I put `Console.ReadLine();` after the for loop, then it looks like it waits till all threads are done.

**Question:** Is there a way I can wait till all threads are finished then proceed to the next step without using `Console.ReadLine();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, you could use `Parallel.ForEach` to accomplish the same thing:

```
string[] urls = { url1, url2, url3, url4 };
Parallel.ForEach(urls, url => PooledFunc(url));
```

`Parallel.ForEach` will not return until all of the items have been processed.

This also allows you to keep the `PooledFunc` declaration nicer:

```
static void PooledFunc(string url) // Can keep this strongly typed
{
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
```

Comment: @Reed-Thanks! This works perfect! just another quick question, is there significant downside of opening more threads (or the Parallel)? Like nested/recursinve? For example, opening multiple urls under those (4) urls

Comment: @sora0419 Each thread has overhead.  Too many threads can add overhead and not get you any gains.  "Parallel" and similar tools partition to balance that out for you, though.